# express.js next function causing issue some times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my express.js app, I have a POST route (given below). When a user sends a POST request to /response endpoint, the logic under post /response gets executed and then the user gets redirected to another page. Most of the time this flow worked without any issues, but one time I see POST being invoked and then immediately there is an GET call for the post URL which resulted in 404 and none of the code under post /response block got executed

I am wondering if the next function is causing any issue by converting the POST to GET and not letting the code under POST/respone to execute?

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.session.user
  logger.log("PAGE", `Page: ${req.originalUrl}`)
  next()
})

  ...

app.post("/response", [check('id').exists(), check('check').exists()], (req, res) => {
  //logic here
  return res.redirect("page2");
}
```

**Apache log:**

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Mar/2020:21:30:00 -0400] "POST /response?c=val1&id=val2 HTTP/1.1" 302 263
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Mar/2020:21:30:00 -0400] "GET /response?c=val1&id=val2 HTTP/1.1" **404** 15974
```

---

**Edit:** redirect logic

```js
const errors = validationResult(req)

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  logger.log("SEV1E", "Server side validation error " + JSON.stringify(errors))
  sendTranLog(req.query.id, "WC_SEV1_VALI_FAIL", "ERROR")
  return res.redirect("../page?status=e&id=RESP_ERROR&redirect=true")
}

db.run(fresSql, fResVals, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message)
  }
  res.redirect("../page?status=" + respStatus + "&id=" + tuid + "&redirect=true")
})
```

Comment: Right of the bat it seems unlikely (to me at least) that the middleware in your first code block is causing this behaviour. Can you share more of the logic before the `res.redirect`? Also, can you share your client-code? (The code where you are calling this end point)

Comment: const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      logger.log("SEV1E", "Server side validation error " + JSON.stringify(errors));
      sendTranLog(req.query.id, "WC_SEV1_VALI_FAIL", "ERROR")
      return res.redirect("../page?status=e&id=RESP_ERROR&redirect=true");
    }
      db.run(fresSql, fResVals, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
        }
        res.redirect("../page?status=" + respStatus + "&id=" + tuid + "&redirect=true");
      });

Comment: client is another third party service, which does POST to my URL